# Android development using processing sketches

Tags: android, arduino, processing

I'm a embedded systems engineer. I would like all my electronic goods (robots, quad copters, etc.) to be controlled using my Android device ([Galaxy Nexus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Nexus)). I heard that [Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) sketches are way easy when compared to orthodox methods of creating Android applications.

My aim is to create Android applications (more likely an interface with buttons and sliders to control my bots and maybe some animations just for fun) using Processing sketches to control my robots, and I would also like to use my phone's sensors (accelerometers, gyro, ambient light, etc.) for controlling my bot. Is it a good idea to use Processing for my purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Controlling Arduino with Android using Processing](http://stream.tellart.com/controlling-arduino-with-android/)* may be similar to what you're looking for.

As far as I know, this library only gives you basic serial communication between the Processing sketch and an Arduino. I belive it doesn't support chips besides the [ATmega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR#Device_overview), and it doesn't support wireless communication, but serial communication is fairly standardized, so you may have luck with other serial devices.

Keep in mind that Processing for Android is not optimized for performance, since the underlying `PApplet` class constantly calls your `draw()` method, and thus spins CPU and possibly redraws graphics. You'll drain battery life pretty quickly. If you plan on sticking an Android on a quad copter and controlling over the web, you'll have better luck with a dedicated wireless device such as the [Xbee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) for the wireless portion. You could still use the Android + Arduino/Whatever + Client Xbee for the "remote". One last disadvantage is that it may be tricky getting core API access while in Processing for Arduino. The standard Processing functions + plumbing have been ported over nicely, but if you may end up on your own if you try to, for example, make a phone call or prevent the phone from sleeping.

That all being said, once you are all set up, Processing + Android is a piece of cake. It sure beats having to go through the entire development chain for a normal application, and you don't have to write any [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29)-equivalents. Best yet, it'll give you some flexibility in controlling your device via your computer or through an Android device.

Answer (score 2):

The Ketai libraries for Android Processing will help you. There is a specific sensor library from Ketai that provides simple access to the device's sensors such as accelerometer, tilt, GPS, etc.